# Swift Filtering a Collection Based on Another Collection

Tags: swift

I have two classes "Receipe" and "Incredient". A receipe can have a list of incredients. Now, I want that when I pass in a list of incredient I should get all the receipies back which contain that incredient. Here is what I have:

How can I filter the receipies based on the passed in incrediants.

```
class Recipe {

    var name :String!
    var incredients :[Incredient]!

    init(name :String, incredients :[Incredient]) {
        self.name = name
        self.incredients = incredients
    }

}

class Incredient {
    var name :String!

    init(name :String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

var incredientsToSearchFor = [Incredient(name:"Salt"),Incredient(name :"Sugar")]

var receipe1 = Recipe(name: "Receipe 1", incredients: [Incredient(name: "Salt"),Incredient(name :"Pepper"),Incredient(name :"Water"),Incredient(name :"Sugar")])

var receipe2 = Recipe(name: "Receipe 2", incredients: [Incredient(name: "Salt"),Incredient(name :"Pepper"),Incredient(name :"Water"),Incredient(name :"Sugar")])

var receipe3 = Recipe(name: "Receipe 3", incredients: [Incredient(name :"Pepper"),Incredient(name :"Water"),Incredient(name :"Sugar")])

var receipies = [receipe1,receipe2,receipe3] // list of all the recipies

func getRecipiesByIncrediants(incredients :[Incredient]) -> [Recipe] {

    // WHAT TO DO HERE 

    return nil
}

let matchedRecipies = getRecipiesByIncrediants(incredientsToSearchFor)
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. When you pass `Salt` and `Sugar` into `getRecipiesByIncrediants`, do you expect to get: (a) all recipes that contain salt OR sugar; (b) all recipes that contain salt AND sugar; (c) all recipes that have only salt & sugar, no other ingredients? Also big spelling error: it's "ingredients" not "incredient"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things need to change.

First, these are data models, so they should probably be `struct` types instead of `class`. This allows you to remove the initializer and optionals too:

```
struct Recipe : Equatable {
    let name: String
    let ingredients: [Ingredient]
}

struct Ingredient : Equatable {
    let name : String
}
```

You'll notice I also made them `Equatable`. This is so you can use `contains` to find them in an array. Without it, `contains` won't know whether two of these types are equal.

To conform to Equatable, just add the `==` methods:

```
func ==(lhs: Ingredient, rhs: Ingredient) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}

func ==(lhs: Recipe, rhs: Recipe) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.ingredients == rhs.ingredients
}
```

Creating your data is roughly the same. I fixed some spelling errors and changed `var` to `let` since these values don't change:

```
let ingredientsToSearchFor = [Ingredient(name:"Salt"), Ingredient(name :"Sugar")]

let recipe1 = Recipe(name: "Recipe 1", ingredients: [Ingredient(name: "Salt"), Ingredient(name :"Pepper"), Ingredient(name :"Water"), Ingredient(name :"Sugar")])

let recipe2 = Recipe(name: "Recipe 2", ingredients: [Ingredient(name: "Salt"), Ingredient(name :"Pepper"), Ingredient(name :"Water"), Ingredient(name :"Sugar")])

let recipe3 = Recipe(name: "Recipe 3", ingredients: [Ingredient(name :"Pepper"), Ingredient(name :"Water"), Ingredient(name :"Sugar")])

let recipes = [recipe1, recipe2, recipe3] // list of all the recipes
```

Now on to the filtering. There's more efficient ways to do this, but for ease of reading you can use `filter` and `reduce`:

```
func getRecipesByIngredients(incredients :[Ingredient]) -> [Recipe] {
    return recipes.filter { recipe in
        incredients.reduce(true) { currentValue, ingredient in
            return currentValue && (recipe.ingredients.contains(ingredient))
        }
    }
}
```

`filter` returns a new array containing only elements where the block returns `true`. `reduce` consolidates an entire array into one value (in this case `true` or `false`). So we iterate through each recipe, and check whether all of the specified ingredients are in it.

To call the method:

```
let matchedRecipes = getRecipesByIngredients(ingredientsToSearchFor)
```

This returns recipes 1 and 2 because both contain salt and sugar.

If you want recipes that contain salt OR sugar, use `reduce(false)` and change `&&` to `||`.